# Python PyQt5 numpy Image Rotater cutting edges

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pyqt5

This is my image rotaer, my problem is that the corners of the image are cut off. I also tried to change my label size, but it didn't work. Is there a way to make it bigger so the corners are no longer cut off or is there another way to solve the problem?

```
import sys
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import cv2

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform, QImage, QColor, qRgb
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, pyqtSlot, Qt


class ImageRotater(QWidget):
    isStoping = False
    stepsLeft = -1
    countAngle = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.bilder = []
        self.getBilder()
        rbild = random.choice(tuple(self.bilder))

        self.item = cv2.imread(rbild,1)

        self.item = cv2.flip(self.item, 1)
        self.item = cv2.cvtColor(self.item, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.item = rotate_image(self.item, 90)
        self.modi = rotate_image(self.item, 0)
        im_np = np.array(self.modi)
        im_np = np.transpose(im_np, (1, 0, 2)).copy()
        self.im = QImage(im_np, im_np.shape[1], im_np.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.im = QPixmap(self.im)
        self.transform = QTransform()
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.angle = 0
        self.Spbutton = QPushButton('Stop', self)
        self.Spbutton.clicked.connect(self.stopButton)
        self.Spbutton.setEnabled(False)
        self.Spbutton.move(100, 70)
        self.Sbutton = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.Sbutton.clicked.connect(self.startButton)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.im)
        
        self.label.setGeometry(0,0,1000,1000)
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.Sbutton,1,0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.Spbutton, 2, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.transfromer)
        self.setWindowTitle("Bild")

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def startButton(self):
        self.Sbutton.setEnabled(False)
        self.Spbutton.setEnabled(True)
        self.timer.start(800)
        self.isStoping = False
        self.stepsLeft = -1
       # self.countAngle = 0


    def getBilder(self):
        relevant_path = "./"
        included_extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'png', 'gif', 'svg']
        file_names = [fn for fn in os.listdir(relevant_path)
                      if any(fn.endswith(ext) for ext in included_extensions)]


        self.bilder = file_names


    def transfromer(self):

        self.countAngle += 45

        if self.countAngle == 360:
            self.countAngle = 0

        if self.isStoping == False:

            self.modi = rotate_image(self.item, self.countAngle)
            im_np = np.array(self.modi)
            im_np = np.transpose(im_np, (1, 0, 2)).copy()
            self.im = QPixmap(QImage(im_np, im_np.shape[1], im_np.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888))
            self.label.setPixmap(self.im)

        elif self.stepsLeft > 0:
            self.modi = rotate_image(self.item, self.countAngle)
            im_np = np.array(self.modi)
            im_np = np.transpose(im_np, (1, 0, 2)).copy()
            self.im = QPixmap(QImage(im_np, im_np.shape[1], im_np.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888))
            self.label.setPixmap(self.im)

            self.stepsLeft -= 1
        else:
            self.Sbutton.setEnabled(True)
            self.countAngle -= 45
            self.timer.stop()
    def roll(self):

        zufall = random.randint(0, 1)

        if zufall == 0:
            self.stepsLeft = ((360-self.countAngle) / 45)
            return

        if self.countAngle > 180:
            self.stepsLeft = ((360 - self.countAngle) / 45)
            self.stepsLeft += 4
        else:
            self.stepsLeft = ((180 - self.countAngle) / 45)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def stopButton(self):
        self.isStoping = True
        self.roll()
        self.Spbutton.setEnabled(False)
        if self.stepsLeft <= 2:
            self.stepsLeft += 8

def rotate_image(image, angle):
    image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape[1::-1]) / 2)
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0)
    result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[1::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ImageRotater()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the result when I start the rotation:

[image: Output]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/01/20/opencv-rotate-image/

Comment: @JeruLuke I have already seen this block entry, unfortunately this has not helped me, because I display my image with the framework and not with cv2

Comment: so? the principles are the same. you need to calculate a new, larger, size. Qt has nothing to do with this, not at all. you _really_ need to review [mre], and present a MRE.